# How to create a link or button to a workflow from a list page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I'd like to display a direct link to a given workflow on a particular page. 
Is this possible?

Comment: I see you are asking 2010 questions mainly (and not marking them as answered), so you might be out of luck.  The Workflow Manager in 2013 was overhauled and allows workflows to be started by script. Search for start workflow here on StackOverflow

Comment: Hello Danny, you are right at the moment stuck with 2010. And apologies I believe I have been marking them answered. I need to take a look again. Thank you. Have you any ideas on my question that you may be able to share please?

Comment: Yes, 2010. And I believe I have been marking them answered. I will go and ascertain. Thank you.

Comment: Never tried it on 2010, all I know is that the start workflow code I shared here on SO is reported by 2010 users to not work on 2010